# r join words if in between numbers

Tags: r, gsub

```
a <- c("it is ZZ10 AS 1234 and ZZ10 ASD 123")
```

How can i join words if it has got only 2 alphabets is in between the alphanumeric and number

Expected output

```
"it is ZZ10AS1234 and ZZ10 ASD 123"
```

Comment: `gsub("(\\d) (\\w\\w) (\\d)", "\\1\\2\\3", a)`

Comment: please add this as answer, its working fine @GKi

Comment: Is this relay what you wanted? I haven't understand *is in between the alphanumeric and number* - Currently its only in case between *numbers*.

Comment: alphanumeric would be better, but this too solves my problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can join words if it has got only 2 alphabets and is in between the alphanumeric and number with:

```
gsub("([[:alnum:]]) (\\w\\w) (\\d)", "\\1\\2\\3", a)
#[1] "it is ZZ10AS1234 and ZZ10 ASD 123"
```